# PHP Get Experience by Level

Tags: php, math, numbers

I have this piece of code that loops 1 through 99 and is a formula.

```
function getExperienceByLevel ($maxLevel)
{
    $levels = array ();
    $current = 0;

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $maxLevel; $i++)
    {
        $levels[$i - 1] = floor ($current / 4);
        $current +=  floor($i+300*pow(2, ($i/9.75)));
    }

    return $levels;
}
```

First you initiate it like so `$aLevels = getExperienceByLevel(99);` then to see how much EXP you need to get to level `6` you do this `echo $aLevels[5];` since it's an array.

Now I'm trying to do reverse. Get Level by EXP.

```
function getLevelByExp($exp) 
{
    $myLevel = 0;
    $aLevels = getExperienceByLevel(99);

    for ($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++)
    {
        if ($exp > $aLevels[$i-1]) 
        { 
            return $myLevel;
        }
    }
}
```

When called upon `getLevelByExp(1124);` or any number inside, it seems to return a zero. But it seems to work when you put echos inside that statement.

Like instead of `return $myLevel` do `echo "You are up to level $i<br />";` and it will go all the way up to the current level you've gained EXP for.

But still.. doesn't work when I want to simply return a number.

Comment: A note on the design here... It might be better to create your `$aLevels` array OUTSIDE of this function and pass it in as an argument, like `function getLevelByExp ($exp, $aLevels)`. This way you can call `getLevelByExp` multiple times without adding the extra overhead of repeated `getExperienceByLevel` calls. It will also decouple the two functions so you can reason about each individually instead of having to know all about one to understand the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work better than your function:

```
function getLevelByExp($exp)
{
        $aLevels = getExperienceByLevel(99);
        for ($i = 0;  $i <= 99;  ++$i)
        {
                //echo "cmp $exp >= aLevels[$i]={$aLevels[$i]}\n";
                if ($exp <= $aLevels[$i])
                        return $i - 1;
        }
        return -1;
}
```

It needs improvement for the edge cases, such as when `$exp` is zero.

Comment: Level 1 is EXP 0 through 79... however doing... say  `getLevelByExp(50)` it outputs `0` when it should be `1`...

Comment: @weka:  I eyeballed the correctness of the output assuming it was using tank level approximation.  If it is always one less, then change `return $i - 1`  to `return $i`.

Comment: Ah, right. But then doing `echo getLevelByExp(3145);` still says 1 when it shouldn't... http://i.imgur.com/gEYgu.png

Answer (score 1):

Return $i instead because it always '0'

```
if ($exp > $aLevels[$i-1]) { 
        return $i;
    }
```

Comment: the "$myLevel" value not touched after you initialized it

Comment: My code must be wrong since no matter what.. say `getLevelByExp(11190);` outputs `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You never change `$myLevel`, so it will always stay at `0`.

Try returning `$i` instead of `$myLevel`, as `$i` is actually changing:

```
function getLevelByExp($exp) {
    $aLevels = getExperienceByLevel(99);

    for ($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++) {
        if ($exp > $aLevels[$i-1]) { 
            return $i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Level 1 is EXP 0 through 79... however doing... say  `getLevelByExp(50)` it outputs `0` when it should be `1`...

Comment: Wait. It does out. But doing like `echo getLevelByExp(190);` still outputs `1` when it should `3`... reff: http://i.imgur.com/gEYgu.png